# No filesystem found for scheme hdfs - org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:456)

Tags: cloudera-manager, apache-beam-io

I am using **Cloudera Enterprise 6.1.0 version** and facing this issue with **apache beam 2.11 SDKs** when reading or writing any file on **HDFS** with SparkRunner. But, with the spark, it is working.

This issue is coming after upgrading **Cloudera version from 5.14.0 to 6.1.0**
at the older version, it was working fine with following code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkContextOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.RowCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResourceId;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.hdfs.HadoopFileSystemOptions;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //HadoopFileSystemOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(HadoopFileSystemOptions.class);
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                    .setMaster("yarn")
                    .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
                    .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
                    .set("spark.executor.cores", "5")
                .set("spark.executor.instances", "30")
                .set("spark.executor.memory","8g");

        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        jsc.setLogLevel("ERROR");

        SparkContextOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(SparkContextOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
        options.setUsesProvidedSparkContext(true);
        options.setProvidedSparkContext(jsc);

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS","hdfs://host1:8020");
         UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        try {
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("test@EIO.COM", "/opt/app/kerbfiles/test.keytab");
            if(UserGroupInformation.isLoginKeytabBased()){
                UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().reloginFromKeytab();
            }else if(UserGroupInformation.isLoginTicketBased()){
                UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().reloginFromTicketCache();
            }
        }catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("*******************************8");
        p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from("hdfs://host1:8020/hdfsdata/input/Reg_Employee.txt"))

        .apply("WriteCounts", TextIO.write().to("hdfs://host1:8020/tmp/test"));
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
```

**The Following is the Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No filesystem found for scheme hdfs
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.getFileSystemInternal(FileSystems.java:456)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchNewResource(FileSystems.java:526)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(FileBasedSink.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$TypedWrite.to(TextIO.java:700)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$Write.to(TextIO.java:1027)
    at Test.main(Test.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Need help on this matter.

Thank You

Nikhil

Comment: Any luck? Any chance you might already have a solution to this?

Comment: After changing the hadoop jars, it got resolved

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons:

1. Service files are wrongly merged or wrong service file on classpath.
   Some of your dependency on classpath doens't contain `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` in 
   `META-INF/services/org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`. So if it's loaded first you cannot find class, which initiate HDFS. For example `hadoop-common.jar` doesn't have `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem` in service file, but `hadoop-hdfs.jar` has it correctly.

   What to do - if the wrong service file comes from fatjar, merge service files.
   E.g in gradle

```
shadowJar {
   mergeServiceFiles() 
}
```

Or use version of your runner with prebuilt hadoop, it should be merged correctly.

2. set `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf"`. Or path where you hdfs configs are. Make sure user which runs spark/flink can see this environment variable.
3. You didn't add dependency

   `"org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-hadoop-file-system:${beamVersion}"`

   So beam doesn't know this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Add `HadoopFileSystemOptions` solved my problem:

```
    val conf = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hadoop-namenode-5:9000")
    conf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem")
    val options=PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).as(classOf[HadoopFileSystemOptions])
```

Code from：
[zqiangliu's Beam Example](https://github.com/zqiangliu/beam-demo/blob/4acf43a581945abce9bd35db50e9e69820208901/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/demos/HdfsReadWriteDemo.java)

Comment: Please take your time to format the answer properly